# Which recyclerview version do i use for Support repository 25

Tags: android

I am a an android studio beginner,i have been following a tutorial on using the recyclerview,I saw the tutorial succesfully use `'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'`

but when i tried to use it i got the error

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:23.0.+:
```

i have android studio 1.4 and my Android Support Repository is 25 and is upto date. should i be using a different recyclerview version in dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to avoid the `+` when importing libraries. This can lead to errors, because the library gets new updates automatically. Check if you have the updated `Android Support Library`(`23.1.1`) in your SDK Manager.

The latest version and correct import is:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: the 23.1.1 library is installed and not showing any option to update,

Comment: Mark my answer as correct then :)
For the next time you get that error, try this: right click on `app` folder in `Android Studio` -> `Open Module Settings` -> open tab `dependencies` -> click on the `+` on the right -> `1 Library dependency` -> enter a part of the name of your desired library -> press enter -> click on the right library, which should always be the latest one.
Also, Android Studio suggests to use a newer version of a library, if the `import code` is highlighted - press `alt` and `enter` to get suggestions on what to do.